# UWP Style X:binding of margin to a function throws a System.AccessViolationException. Any ideas why, when this works fine if set in inline xaml?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, resourcedictionary

I have some methods that I x:bind to, to set element size based on the size of the host control. All works well except when binding a function to the Margin property in my user control (from style dictionary) I am getting a System.AccessViolationException.

I do not get the exception if binding to the element directly -just when used in a style setter. Obviously can work around this by setting the property on the xaml for the object but would like to know if this is a bug or if I am missing something? The function binding from the dictionary works with all other properties that I am using (just not on Margin). Any advice or guidance would be appreciated.

**XAML Snippet:**

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
    <Style TargetType="Path" x:Key="Ball.Shadow">
       <Setter Property="Height" Value="{x:Bind DimensionAsFraction(0.5)}" />
        ...
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="Ball.Letter" BasedOn="{StaticResource Ball.Text}">
       <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{x:Bind MarginAsFraction(0.075), Mode=OneWay}" />
    ...
 </style>
```

> object.Height is the height of the host control - this has been set
> before the component is initialised and works fine when referenced
> from other code and style setters.

**Code Snippet:**

```
public sealed partial class Example : UserControl
{
     private void SetDefaults()
     {
        Height = 200;
        Width = 200;
     }

     private int calculateAsInt(double fraction) => (int)(object.Height * fraction);
 
     private double DimensionAsFraction(double fraction) => calculateAsInt(fraction);

     private Thickness MarginAsFraction(double fraction) => new Thickness(0, calculateAsInt(fraction), 0, 0);

     private Thickness BorderAsFraction(double fraction) => new Thickness(calculateAsInt(fraction));

    public Example()
    {
        SetDefaults();
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UWP Style X:binding of margin to a function throws a System.AccessViolationException. Any ideas why, when this works fine if set in inline xaml?

I'm afraid you can't use binding or x:bind in the style setter, derive from [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Setter?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=winrt-19041#migration-notes)

> Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) and Microsoft Silverlight supported the ability to use a Binding expression to supply the Value for a Setter in a Style. The Windows Runtime doesn't support a Binding usage for Setter.Value (the Binding won't evaluate and the Setter has no effect, you won't get errors, but you won't get the desired result either). When you convert XAML styles from Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) or Microsoft Silverlight XAML, replace any Binding expression usages with strings or objects that set values, or refactor the values as shared {StaticResource} markup extension values rather than Binding -obtained values.

For this scenario, we suggest set margin in the control directly

```
<TextBlock Text="Hello World" Margin="{x:Bind MarginAsFraction(0.75)}" />
```

Comment: Thankyou Nico. That does indeed answer my question. I appreciate your time and have a follow up question if you are available to answer it....

What are your thoughts on some of the binding expressions that are clearly being evaluated and giving the effect required for me (for example:
 <Setter Property="Width" Value="{x:Bind DimensionAsFraction(0.8)}" />
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="{x:Bind DimensionAsFraction(0.4)}" />).

Would you agree that these shouldn't be working and are in fact a bug given the information that you provided? 

Many Thanks

Comment: Yep, your x:bind is clearly, unfortunately, it's not allowed in the UWP platform within style setter. it's not a bug, it's by-design.

Comment: Thanks Nico. You rock!

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this thread attempting to solve a similar problem which resulted in a Stack Overflow Error:

```
<Style TargetType="GridViewItem">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{x:Bind MyMargin, Mode=OneWay"/>
</Style>
```

For my use case, I did not feel that setting the control's margin was appropriate because doing so meant that the selection box (when using then keyboard) was not around the control, but the control and margin.  Since I have a non-uniform margin, it did not look right.

My solution was to set in code behind in the Page SizeChanged event (since that is when and why I am changing the margin).

```
Dim Width As Integer = SomeFunctionOf(WindowSize.Width)
Dim NewMargin As New Thickness(Width, 0, Width, 0)
Dim MarginStyle As New Style(GetType(GridViewItem)) 
MarginStyle.Setters.Add(New Setter(MarginProperty, NewMargin))
MyGridView.ItemContainerStyle = MarginStyle
```

Not optimum, but it worked for me. Perhaps this will help someone in the future.

--- Update ---

After I posted this, I got to thinking about it and realized I could use the same code above, but instead of setting **MyGridView.ItemContainerStyle** in code, I could instead set a Property in my ViewModel, such as **MyViewModel.MarignStyle = MarginStyle**.  Then, use binding with:

```
<GridView x:Name="MyGridView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyViewModel.ItemsView, Mode=OneTime}" ItemContainerStyle="{x:Bind MyViewModel.MarginStyle,Mode=OneWay}">
```

In any case, both versions work for me.